# Changing the color of status bar

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview

What is the guideline for changing the color of status bar. If I change its color, do I need to change the color of other UI widgets like Navigation bar etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the color of the `UINavigationController`, then the corresponding buttons, like Back and any other additional buttons will automatically be changed as well. Same goes for the `UIToolBar`.

As far as the "Status Bar" which houses the clock, battery info, etc. You don't necessarily need to change anything else in your app. Typically if you have a darker themed appearance, you would want to use a darker StatusBar, it's really your preference, but you would want to go with what looks best and would be understandable by thge typical user.

Answer (score 2):

```
[application setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque];
[application setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent];
```

you can use these for changing status bar in

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

this method

automatially change in UI widgets.

Answer (score 1):

There is no guideline specifically for how you should match your status bar color with your user interface colors.

If you feel a black/dark navigation bar should go with a black status bar, by all means set the navigation bar's `tintColor` as such. If you feel that you want your app to have a black status bar regardless of the color scheme, Apple will not stop you from doing that either.

You can design your app however you like, as long as it doesn't stray too far from the general iOS [human interface guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556).

Answer (score 0):

The best to add in view controller:

```
- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle{ 
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent; 
}
```